# Permission denied error when using docker import

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, docker, command

With docker, when I want to import a image from local file system I get an error.

This is the command I am using:

```
sudo cat Downloads/debian-6.0-x86_64-minimal.tar.gz  |docker import - debi
```

The result:

```
Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.20/images/create?fromSrc=-&repo=debi: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied.

* Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?

* Is your docker daemon up and running?
```

How can I deal with it?

Comment: On what OS are you using docker? ARe you using it through a VirtualBox? What version of docker are you using?

Comment: Hi, it could be that, docker command is missing the sudo

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your Daemon is actually running?

```
sudo docker info
```

If it doesn't give you your docker info then your daemon isn't set up correctly.
This usually happens to me when I've rebooted my machine.

```
sudo service docker restart
```

or

```
sudo docker -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -d &
```

Hope this helps